# FabricJS resize JSON data for different screensize

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm using fabricJS for freeDrawingMode and saving the drawing to my database via JSON. My canvas is a dynamic size based on the screen size of the device opening the page. When loading the JSON data the next time the page is opened, if the window size isn't the exact same size as previous, the drawing is either way to big or small for the canvas on the new screen. How do I parse the JSON data to properly scale the drawing?

I'm loading JSON via `canvas.loadFromJSON(data, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));`

Canvas build:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('sheet');
canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 1
canvas.setHeight((window.innerHeight / 5) - 20);
canvas.setWidth(document.getElementById("sheet-container").clientWidth);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Example of JSON in database

```
{"version":"5.2.4","objects":[{"type":"path","version":"5.2.4","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":48.4,"top":-31.89,"width":925.15,"height":124.59,"fill":null,"stroke":"#ff0000","strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"round","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"round","strokeUniform":false,"strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","skewX":0,"skewY":0,"path":[["M",108.78159292837717,83.38707494274483],["Q",108.78259292837717,83.38607494274483,115.2696282864914,79.9525306803965],["Q",121.75666364460562,76.5189864180482,148.2038077969175,64.7468346614254],["Q",174.65095194922938,52.9746829048026,197.6050770625567,44.636075410528115],["Q",220.559202175884,36.29746791625363,243.01432456935635,29.920885714749616],["Q",265.46944696282867,23.5443035132456,284.93055303717136,18.63924028131943],["Q",304.39165911151406,13.734177049393265,324.3517679057117,9.810126463852333],["Q",344.31187669990936,5.8860758783114,362.27597461468724,2.4525316159630832],["Q",380.2400725294651,-0.9810126463852333,394.7111514052584,-1.9620252927704667],["Q",409.1822302810517,-2.9430379391557,424.6513145965549,-3.9240505855409333],["Q",440.1203989120581,-4.9050632319261664,451.09845874886673,-4.9050632319261664],["Q",462.07651858567544,-4.9050632319261664,472.5555757026292,-4.41455690873355],["Q",483.034632819583,-3.9240505855409333,492.01668177697195,-2.4525316159630832],["Q",500.9987307343609,-0.9810126463852333,509.4817769718949,-0.49050632319261667],["Q",517.9648232094289,0,524.4518585675431,1.47151896957785],["Q",530.9388939256573,2.9430379391557,534.9309156844969,4.41455690873355],["Q",538.9229374433364,5.8860758783114,541.4179510426111,6.8670885246966336],["Q",543.9129646418858,7.848101171081867,545.9089755213056,8.8291138174671],["Q",547.9049864007253,9.810126463852333,549.900997280145,10.30063278704495],["Q",551.8970081595648,10.791139110237568,553.8930190389847,11.772151756622801],["Q",555.8890299184044,12.753164403008034,556.8870353581142,13.24367072620065],["Q",557.8850407978241,13.734177049393265,558.883046237534,13.734177049393265],["Q",559.8810516772439,13.734177049393265,560.3800543970989,14.224683372585883],["Q",560.8790571169538,14.715189695778498,561.8770625566638,14.715189695778498],["Q",562.8750679963736,14.715189695778498,563.3740707162285,14.715189695778498],["Q",563.8730734360835,14.715189695778498,564.3720761559384,15.205696018971116],["Q",564.8710788757934,15.696202342163733,565.8690843155032,16.18670866535635],["Q",566.8670897552131,16.677214988548965,567.3660924750681,17.16772131174158],["Q",567.865095194923,17.6582276349342,568.8631006346329,17.6582276349342],["Q",569.8611060743427,17.6582276349342,570.8591115140525,18.148733958126815],["Q",571.8571169537624,18.63924028131943,572.3561196736174,18.63924028131943],["Q",572.8551223934724,18.63924028131943,574.3521305530372,19.12974660451205],["Q",575.8491387126021,19.620252927704666,576.847144152312,20.11075925089728],["Q",577.8451495920218,20.6012655740899,580.3401631912965,21.582278220475132],["Q",582.8351767905712,22.563290866860363,585.3301903898459,23.5443035132456],["Q",587.8252039891206,24.525316159630833,591.3182230281052,25.996835129208684],["Q",594.8112420670898,27.46835409878653,598.3042611060744,29.430379391556997],["Q",601.797280145059,31.392404684327467,605.7893019038985,32.86392365390532],["Q",609.781323662738,34.33544262348317,613.2743427017226,36.29746791625364],["Q",616.7673617407072,38.2594932090241,619.7613780598368,39.24050585540933],["Q",622.7553943789665,40.22151850179456,625.2504079782411,41.2025311481798],["Q",627.7454215775159,42.18354379456503,630.7394378966455,43.164556440950264],["Q",633.7334542157752,44.145569087335495,636.22846781505,45.12658173372073],["Q",638.7234814143246,46.107594380105965,640.7194922937445,47.579113349683816],["Q",642.7155031731642,49.050632319261666,644.7115140525839,49.541138642454285],["Q",646.7075249320037,50.0316449656469,648.2045330915685,51.01265761203213],["Q",649.7015412511332,51.99367025841736,651.697552130553,52.48417658160998],["Q",653.6935630099729,52.9746829048026,655.6895738893927,53.46518922799521],["Q",657.6855847688124,53.95569555118783,659.1825929283773,54.44620187438045],["Q",660.679601087942,54.93670819757306,662.6756119673618,55.91772084395829],["Q",664.6716228467815,56.89873349034353,667.1666364460561,57.38923981353615],["Q",669.6616500453309,57.87974613672877,671.6576609247506,58.37025245992138],["Q",673.6536718041705,58.860758783113994,676.6476881233001,60.332277752691844],["Q",679.6417044424297,61.803796722269695,681.6377153218496,62.294303045462314],["Q",683.6337262012693,62.78480936865493,686.128739800544,63.27531569184755],["Q",688.6237533998187,63.765822015040165,691.6177697189484,64.7468346614254],["Q",694.611786038078,65.72784730781063,696.6077969174978,65.72784730781063],["Q",698.6038077969175,65.72784730781063,701.0988213961923,66.21835363100325],["Q",703.593834995467,66.70885995419586,706.0888485947416,67.19936627738848],["Q",708.5838621940164,67.6898726005811,710.5798730734361,68.18037892377372],["Q",712.575883952856,68.67088524696634,715.5699002719856,68.67088524696634],["Q",718.5639165911152,68.67088524696634,721.5579329102449,68.67088524696634],["Q",724.5519492293745,68.67088524696634,728.543970988214,68.18037892377372],["Q",732.5359927470536,67.6898726005811,736.0290117860382,66.70885995419587],["Q",739.5220308250226,65.72784730781063,744.0130553037171,65.23734098461802],["Q",748.5040797824116,64.7468346614254,752.4961015412512,63.275315691847545],["Q",756.4881233000907,61.803796722269695,759.9811423390753,60.82278407588446],["Q",763.4741613780599,59.841771429499225,767.4661831368994,58.860758783113994],["Q",771.458204895739,57.87974613672877,773.9532184950136,55.9177208439583],["Q",776.4482320942883,53.95569555118783,778.9432456935631,52.48417658160999],["Q",781.4382592928378,51.012657612032136,783.4342701722576,49.541138642454285],["Q",785.4302810516773,48.069619672876435,786.4282864913872,47.088607026491204],["Q",787.4262919310971,46.107594380105965,788.923300090662,44.63607541052812],["Q",790.4203082502268,43.16455644095027,790.9193109700816,42.18354379456504],["Q",791.4183136899366,41.2025311481798,791.4183136899366,39.73101217860195],["Q",791.4183136899366,38.2594932090241,791.9173164097915,36.78797423944625],["Q",792.4163191296466,35.3164552698684,792.4163191296466,33.84493630029055],["Q",792.4163191296466,32.3734173307127,792.4163191296466,29.920885714749616],["Q",792.4163191296466,27.46835409878653,791.9173164097915,25.996835129208684],["Q",791.4183136899366,24.525316159630833,790.4203082502268,22.07278454366775],["Q",789.4223028105168,19.620252927704666,788.4242973708069,17.6582276349342],["Q",787.4262919310971,15.696202342163733,784.9312783318223,13.243670726200651],["Q",782.4362647325477,10.791139110237568,779.4422484134179,9.319620140659717],["Q",776.4482320942883,7.848101171081867,773.9532184950136,6.376582201504016],["Q",771.458204895739,4.9050632319261664,767.9651858567543,3.9240505855409333],["Q",764.4721668177697,2.9430379391557,760.4801450589302,1.9620252927704667],["Q",756.4881233000907,0.9810126463852333,750.0010879419765,0.9810126463852333],["Q",743.5140525838623,0.9810126463852333,734.5320036264734,1.4715189695778501],["Q",725.5499546690844,1.9620252927704667,714.5718948322757,3.9240505855409333],["Q",703.593834995467,5.8860758783114,692.1167724388033,8.8291138174671],["Q",680.6397098821398,11.7721517566228,670.659655485041,14.224683372585883],["Q",660.679601087942,16.677214988548965,654.1925657298278,19.620252927704662],["Q",647.7055303717136,22.563290866860363,640.7194922937445,25.015822482823445],["Q",633.7334542157752,27.46835409878653,625.7494106980962,30.41139203794223],["Q",617.7653671804171,33.35442997709793,608.7833182230281,35.80696159306102],["Q",599.8012692656392,38.2594932090241,593.8132366273799,40.71202482498718],["Q",587.8252039891206,43.16455644095027,583.3341795104261,45.61708805691335],["Q",578.8431550317317,48.069619672876435,573.3541251133274,50.52215128883952],["Q",567.865095194923,52.9746829048026,560.3800543970989,55.91772084395829],["Q",552.8950135992748,58.860758783113994,544.9109700815957,61.803796722269695],["Q",536.9269265639166,64.7468346614254,530.9388939256573,67.19936627738848],["Q",524.9508612873981,69.65189789335156,520.4598368087036,71.61392318612204],["Q",515.9688123300091,73.5759484788925,509.4817769718949,75.04746744847034],["Q",502.9947416137806,76.5189864180482,497.50571169537625,77.99050538762604],["Q",492.0166817769719,79.46202435720389,487.52565729827745,80.44303700358913],["Q",483.034632819583,81.42404964997436,478.0446056210336,83.38607494274483],["Q",473.05457842248416,85.34810023551529,469.0625566636446,85.83860655870791],["Q",465.07053490480513,86.32911288190054,460.5795104261107,87.31012552828577],["Q",456.0884859474162,88.29113817467099,452.09646418857665,88.78164449786361],["Q",448.1044424297371,89.27215082105623,443.1144152311877,89.27215082105623],["Q",438.1243880326383,89.27215082105623,434.13236627379877,90.25316346744147],["Q",430.1403445149593,91.2341761138267,426.1483227561197,91.72468243701931],["Q",422.15630099728014,92.21518876021193,417.66527651858564,92.21518876021193],["Q",413.1742520398912,92.21518876021193,408.68322756119676,92.21518876021193],["Q",404.1922030825023,92.21518876021193,398.70317316409796,92.70569508340455],["Q",393.2141432456936,93.19620140659717,387.72511332728925,93.19620140659717],["Q",382.23608340888484,93.19620140659717,376.74705349048054,93.19620140659717],["Q",371.25802357207624,93.19620140659717,364.77098821396197,93.19620140659717],["Q",358.2839528558477,93.19620140659717,351.29791477787853,93.19620140659717],["Q",344.31187669990936,93.19620140659717,337.82484134179515,93.19620140659717],["Q",331.33780598368094,93.19620140659717,325.8487760652766,93.19620140659717],["Q",320.3597461468722,93.19620140659717,315.8687216681777,93.19620140659717],["Q",311.37769718948323,93.19620140659717,306.8866727107888,92.70569508340455],["Q",302.39564823209435,92.21518876021193,297.4056210335449,91.23417611382669],["Q",292.4155938349955,90.25316346744145,288.42357207615595,89.76265714424883],["Q",284.4315503173164,89.27215082105623,280.4395285584769,87.80063185147839],["Q",276.4475067996374,86.32911288190054,272.45548504079784,85.3481002355153],["Q",268.4634632819583,84.36708758913007,263.9724388032638,83.38607494274484],["Q",259.48141432456936,82.4050622963596,254.49138712601996,81.91455597316698],["Q",249.50135992747056,81.42404964997436,244.51133272892116,79.4620243572039],["Q",239.52130553037173,77.49999906443344,234.03227561196738,76.5189864180482],["Q",228.54324569356302,75.53797377166296,224.05222121486855,74.55696112527772],["Q",219.56119673617408,73.5759484788925,215.0701722574796,72.10442950931466],["Q",210.57914777878517,70.6329105397368,205.58912058023577,69.16139157015894],["Q",200.59909338168634,67.6898726005811,194.61106074342703,65.72784730781063],["Q",188.62302810516772,63.765822015040165,184.13200362647325,62.78480936865493],["Q",179.6409791477788,61.803796722269695,175.14995466908434,60.82278407588446],["Q",170.65893019038987,59.841771429499225,167.16591115140528,58.860758783113994],["Q",163.67289211242067,57.87974613672877,159.68087035358116,55.9177208439583],["Q",155.68884859474161,53.95569555118783,151.19782411604714,52.97468290480259],["Q",146.70679963735267,51.99367025841736,142.21577515865823,51.01265761203213],["Q",137.72475067996376,50.0316449656469,134.23173164097915,48.06961967287643],["Q",130.73871260199456,46.107594380105965,126.74669084315505,44.63607541052812],["Q",122.75466908431552,43.16455644095027,119.76065276518587,42.67405011775765],["Q",116.76663644605621,42.18354379456503,113.27361740707163,40.71202482498718],["Q",109.78059836808704,39.24050585540933,106.7865820489574,38.74999953221672],["Q",103.79256572982776,38.2594932090241,100.29954669084316,37.27848056263886],["Q",96.80652765185857,36.29746791625363,92.81450589301905,35.3164552698684],["Q",88.82248413417952,34.33544262348317,85.32946509519493,33.84493630029055],["Q",81.83644605621033,33.35442997709793,79.34143245693564,32.3734173307127],["Q",76.84641885766094,31.392404684327467,73.8524025385313,30.901898361134847],["Q",70.85838621940164,30.411392037942232,68.86237533998187,29.920885714749616],["Q",66.86636446056211,29.430379391556997,65.86835902085222,29.430379391556997],["Q",64.87035358114234,29.430379391556997,63.37334542157752,28.93987306836438],["Q",61.8763372620127,28.449366745171766,60.87833182230281,28.449366745171766],["Q",59.88032638259293,28.449366745171766,58.882320942883055,28.449366745171766],["Q",57.88431550317317,28.449366745171766,57.38531278331823,27.958860421979146],["Q",56.88631006346329,27.46835409878653,55.888304623753406,27.46835409878653],["Q",54.89029918404352,27.46835409878653,53.89229374433364,27.46835409878653],["Q",52.89428830462376,27.46835409878653,52.395285584768814,27.46835409878653],["Q",51.89628286491388,27.46835409878653,51.397280145058936,27.46835409878653],["Q",50.89827742520399,27.46835409878653,50.39927470534906,27.46835409878653],["Q",49.900271985494115,27.46835409878653,49.900271985494115,27.958860421979146],["Q",49.900271985494115,28.449366745171766,49.900271985494115,28.93987306836438],["Q",49.900271985494115,29.430379391556997,49.900271985494115,29.920885714749616],["Q",49.900271985494115,30.411392037942232,49.900271985494115,30.901898361134847],["Q",49.900271985494115,31.392404684327467,49.900271985494115,32.3734173307127],["Q",49.900271985494115,33.35442997709793,49.900271985494115,33.84493630029055],["Q",49.900271985494115,34.33544262348317,49.40126926563917,35.80696159306102],["Q",48.90226654578423,37.27848056263886,48.90226654578423,38.2594932090241],["Q",48.90226654578423,39.24050585540933,48.90226654578423,40.71202482498718],["Q",48.90226654578423,42.18354379456503,48.90226654578423,42.67405011775765],["Q",48.90226654578423,43.16455644095027,48.90226654578423,44.63607541052812],["Q",48.90226654578423,46.107594380105965,48.90226654578423,46.598100703298584],["Q",48.90226654578423,47.0886070264912,48.90226654578423,47.579113349683816],["Q",48.90226654578423,48.069619672876435,49.40126926563917,48.56012599606905],["Q",49.900271985494115,49.050632319261666,50.898277425204,49.541138642454285],["Q",51.89628286491388,50.0316449656469,53.89229374433364,50.0316449656469],["Q",55.8883046237534,50.0316449656469,63.37334542157752,49.541138642454285],["Q",70.85838621940164,49.050632319261666,95.30951949229376,43.65506276414288],["Q",119.76065276518587,38.2594932090241,149.70081595648233,33.354429977097936],["Q",179.6409791477788,28.449366745171766,202.5951042611061,23.5443035132456],["Q",225.5492293744334,18.63924028131943,249.0023572076156,14.715189695778498],["Q",272.45548504079784,10.791139110237568,290.4195829555757,8.338607494274484],["Q",308.3836808703536,5.8860758783114,326.3477787851315,1.9620252927704662],["Q",344.31187669990936,-1.9620252927704667,360.27996373526753,-3.9240505855409333],["Q",376.24805077062564,-5.8860758783114,388.72311876699916,-7.848101171081867],["Q",401.1981867633727,-9.810126463852333,411.6772438803264,-11.281645433430183],["Q",422.15630099728014,-12.753164403008034,431.6373526745241,-12.753164403008034],["Q",441.118404351768,-12.753164403008034,449.601450589302,-13.734177049393267],["Q",458.0844968268359,-14.715189695778498,464.0725294650952,-15.205696018971116],["Q",470.0605621033545,-15.696202342163733,473.5535811423391,-15.696202342163733],["Q",477.0466001813237,-15.696202342163733,480.5396192203083,-15.696202342163733],["Q",484.03263825929287,-15.696202342163733,486.02864913871264,-15.696202342163733],["Q",488.0246600181324,-15.696202342163733,489.0226654578423,-15.696202342163733],["Q",490.0206708975522,-15.696202342163733,491.01867633726204,-15.696202342163733],["Q",492.0166817769719,-15.696202342163733,492.51568449682685,-15.696202342163733],["Q",493.0146872166818,-15.696202342163733,494.01269265639166,-15.696202342163733],["Q",495.0106980961016,-15.696202342163733,495.0106980961016,-15.205696018971116],["Q",495.0106980961016,-14.715189695778498,495.50970081595653,-14.715189695778498],["Q",496.0087035358115,-14.715189695778498,496.5077062556664,-14.715189695778498],["Q",497.0067089755213,-14.715189695778498,498.50371713508616,-14.715189695778498],["Q",500.00072529465103,-14.715189695778498,500.9987307343609,-14.715189695778498],["Q",501.99673617407075,-14.715189695778498,503.9927470534905,-14.715189695778498],["Q",505.9887579329103,-14.715189695778498,508.9827742520399,-15.205696018971116],["Q",511.97679057116954,-15.696202342163733,517.9648232094289,-16.18670866535635],["Q",523.9528558476882,-16.677214988548965,533.433907524932,-18.148733958126815],["Q",542.914959202176,-19.620252927704666,554.3920217588396,-20.6012655740899],["Q",565.8690843155033,-21.582278220475136,576.847144152312,-23.544303513245602],["Q",587.8252039891206,-25.506328806016068,599.8012692656391,-27.468354098786534],["Q",611.7773345421577,-29.430379391556997,620.7593834995467,-29.920885714749616],["Q",629.7414324569357,-30.411392037942232,634.7314596554851,-30.901898361134847],["Q",639.7214868540344,-31.392404684327467,644.2125113327289,-31.392404684327467],["Q",648.7035358114234,-31.392404684327467,653.6935630099729,-30.411392037942232],["Q",658.6835902085222,-29.430379391556997,663.6736174070717,-28.449366745171766],["Q",668.6636446056211,-27.46835409878653,674.1526745240254,-25.506328806016064],["Q",679.6417044424297,-23.5443035132456,682.6357207615595,-22.07278454366775],["Q",685.6297370806891,-20.6012655740899,688.6237533998187,-18.63924028131943],["Q",691.6177697189484,-16.677214988548965,693.1147778785132,-15.205696018971114],["Q",694.611786038078,-13.734177049393265,695.6097914777879,-12.753164403008032],["Q",696.6077969174978,-11.7721517566228,697.1067996373528,-10.30063278704495],["Q",697.6058023572077,-8.8291138174671,697.6058023572077,-7.848101171081867],["Q",697.6058023572077,-6.867088524696633,697.6058023572077,-5.395569555118783],["Q",697.6058023572077,-3.9240505855409333,697.6058023572077,-2.4525316159630832],["Q",697.6058023572077,-0.9810126463852333,697.6058023572077,0],["Q",697.6058023572077,0.9810126463852333,696.6077969174978,1.9620252927704667],["Q",695.6097914777879,2.9430379391557,694.611786038078,4.9050632319261664],["Q",693.6137805983682,6.867088524696633,692.6157751586583,7.848101171081867],["Q",691.6177697189484,8.8291138174671,689.6217588395286,10.30063278704495],["Q",687.6257479601089,11.7721517566228,686.627742520399,13.243670726200648],["Q",685.6297370806891,14.715189695778498,684.6317316409792,16.18670866535635],["Q",683.6337262012693,17.6582276349342,683.1347234814143,18.63924028131943],["Q",682.6357207615595,19.620252927704666,681.6377153218496,20.6012655740899],["Q",680.6397098821398,21.582278220475136,680.1407071622848,22.07278454366775],["Q",679.6417044424297,22.563290866860363,679.6417044424297,23.053797190052983],["Q",679.6417044424297,23.5443035132456,680.1407071622848,24.034809836438214],["Q",680.6397098821398,24.525316159630833,681.6377153218496,25.015822482823452],["Q",682.6357207615595,25.506328806016068,684.6317316409792,25.996835129208684],["Q",686.6277425203989,26.4873414524013,688.6237533998187,26.4873414524013],["Q",690.6197642792386,26.4873414524013,695.110788757933,27.958860421979146],["Q",699.6018132366274,29.430379391556997,706.0888485947416,29.920885714749616],["Q",712.575883952856,30.411392037942232,721.0589301903899,32.3734173307127],["Q",729.5419764279238,34.33544262348317,738.0250226654579,35.3164552698684],["Q",746.5080689029919,36.29746791625363,753.4941069809611,37.76898688583148],["Q",760.4801450589302,39.24050585540933,765.9691749773347,40.22151850179456],["Q",771.458204895739,41.2025311481798,776.9472348141433,41.69303747137242],["Q",782.4362647325477,42.18354379456503,786.9272892112422,43.65506276414288],["Q",791.4183136899366,45.12658173372073,794.9113327289213,45.617088056913346],["Q",798.4043517679058,46.107594380105965,800.8993653671805,46.598100703298584],["Q",803.3943789664552,47.0886070264912,806.3883952855848,48.06961967287643],["Q",809.3824116047144,49.050632319261666,811.3784224841343,49.541138642454285],["Q",813.374433363554,50.0316449656469,815.3704442429738,50.0316449656469],["Q",817.3664551223936,50.0316449656469,819.8614687216683,50.52215128883952],["Q",822.356482320943,51.012657612032136,823.8534904805078,51.012657612032136],["Q",825.3504986400726,51.012657612032136,827.3465095194923,51.50316393522475],["Q",829.342520398912,51.99367025841736,830.839528558477,52.48417658160998],["Q",832.3365367180419,52.9746829048026,833.8335448776066,53.46518922799521],["Q",835.3305530371714,53.95569555118783,835.8295557570264,53.95569555118783],["Q",836.3285584768813,53.95569555118783,837.3265639165911,53.95569555118783],["Q",838.324569356301,53.95569555118783,839.3225747960109,53.95569555118783],["Q",840.3205802357209,53.95569555118783,841.8175883952856,54.44620187438045],["Q",843.3145965548505,54.93670819757306,844.3126019945604,55.91772084395829],["Q",845.3106074342703,56.89873349034353,846.3086128739801,56.89873349034353],["Q",847.30661831369,56.89873349034353,848.8036264732548,57.38923981353615],["Q",850.3006346328197,57.87974613672877,851.2986400725296,58.37025245992138],["Q",852.2966455122395,58.860758783113994,853.7936536718043,59.84177142949923],["Q",855.2906618313691,60.822784075884464,856.7876699909339,61.313290399077076],["Q",858.2846781504987,61.803796722269695,859.2826835902086,62.294303045462314],["Q",860.2806890299186,62.78480936865493,861.7776971894833,63.27531569184755],["Q",863.2747053490481,63.765822015040165,865.2707162284679,64.7468346614254],["Q",867.2667271078877,65.72784730781063,869.2627379873074,66.70885995419587],["Q",871.2587488667272,67.6898726005811,873.2547597461469,68.67088524696632],["Q",875.2507706255667,69.65189789335156,876.7477787851315,70.6329105397368],["Q",878.2447869446963,71.61392318612202,879.7417951042612,72.10442950931464],["Q",881.238803263826,72.59493583250726,883.2348141432458,73.08544215569988],["Q",885.2308250226656,73.5759484788925,886.2288304623755,74.55696112527772],["Q",887.2268359020853,75.53797377166296,889.222846781505,76.02848009485558],["Q",891.2188576609248,76.5189864180482,892.7158658204896,77.00949274124082],["Q",894.2128739800544,77.49999906443344,895.7098821396193,77.49999906443344],["Q",897.2068902991841,77.49999906443344,898.7038984587489,77.49999906443344],["Q",900.2009066183138,77.49999906443344,902.6959202175885,77.49999906443344],["Q",905.1909338168632,77.49999906443344,906.687941976428,77.49999906443344],["Q",908.1849501359928,77.49999906443344,910.1809610154125,77.99050538762606],["Q",912.1769718948324,78.48101171081866,914.671985494107,78.48101171081866],["Q",917.1669990933818,78.48101171081866,920.1610154125115,78.48101171081866],["Q",923.1550317316411,78.48101171081866,926.1490480507707,78.48101171081866],["Q",929.1430643699003,78.48101171081866,933.1350861287399,78.48101171081866],["Q",937.1271078875794,78.48101171081866,941.119129646419,78.48101171081866],["Q",945.1111514052585,78.48101171081866,948.1051677243881,78.48101171081866],["Q",951.0991840435178,78.48101171081866,954.5922030825024,78.48101171081866],["Q",958.0852221214869,78.48101171081866,960.0812330009066,78.48101171081866],["Q",962.0772438803265,78.48101171081866,963.5742520398912,78.48101171081866],["Q",965.0712601994561,78.48101171081866,966.069265639166,78.48101171081866],["Q",967.0672710788759,78.48101171081866,967.5662737987309,78.48101171081866],["Q",968.0652765185857,78.48101171081866,969.5622846781505,78.48101171081866],["Q",971.0592928377154,78.48101171081866,972.0572982774253,78.48101171081866],["Q",973.0553037171352,78.48101171081866,973.5543064369901,77.99050538762606],["L",974.054309156845,77.49899906443343]]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

canvas.setZoom(0.3)

or

canvas.setZoom(1.3)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).